# Django cap a DateField value in the database

Tags: django, django-models

Sorry I am very new to Django. I have date of birth (DOB) as a field in my model. I use the DOB to calculate the age and get some values from other dataset.

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The age cannot be higher than 120 years so I raise a `ValidationError` with the registration and update profile forms whenever they enter a DOB of more than 120 years ago.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()
    dob = self.cleaned_data.get('dob')
    age = (date.today() - dob).days / 365
    if age > 120:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Sorry but profiles cannot be registered with more than 120 years old due to scientific data unavailability.')
    elif age < 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Date of birth is in the future. Please enter valid birth date.')
```

However, what if they register as born 119 years ago. In 1 or 2 years, the age would be 121 and my code will fail. Is there a way to always cap the value of the DOB in my database so the DOB is always maximum 120 years old?
I checked the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield) for `DateField` but there is no reference to `MinValueValidator` as in the case of `IntegerField`.

Comment: Based on your description, you can run a task every day that checks for a value in the "dob" column that is greater than 120 years ago. In the task you can handle such cases as you wish, for example by marking each Account instance as invalid, or by sending emails to users, etc.

Comment: When you register the user you are doing the validation at that time after that why you need to check again ? If they kept age as 119 then after 1 to 2 years why you care about this ?

Comment: @Daniel thanks, it sounds like an option. Maybe not everyday but once a month. I see people talking about Celery, a module called `django-background-tasks`. Do you know any best way to do it for this task? A pointer so I search down the right route haha

Comment: @Ahtisham I need to provide some values but there is no data for ages above 120... So I need to coerce it to be 120 max. I thought it would be possible to set a maximum that sort of kept itself at the maximum with a DateField but it seems it is not the case.

Comment: celery is one way to go - but you would also need celery beat - in fact ive found the two together rather difficult to implement - in a similar situation i instead went with an AWS lambda function that ran once a day to comb my database for data that was actionable each day

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I will google on AWS lambda functions and see how I can make it work and post accordingly. I am quite new to Django so keeping things simple is important!

Comment: @user3507584 I think you are overengineering it you don't need to do any cloud or background task for a edge case that will rearly occure and doesn't make sense why would anyone care about age of user after they have successfully registered. Take a look at any social media platform do they restrict you on age ? or deactivate the account once dob has reached more than 120 years ? no they don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to solve this problem, but please note, the following code is untested.

1. In your app, create a file **tasks.py** and add the core logic there
2. Then in **views.py**, create a method/view that calls this task
3. Wire your urls to the view so that incoming requests can trigger the task
4. Set up some system that calls the endpoint as often as needed

**tasks.py**

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedetla
from .models import Account

def handle_age_over_120_years():
    """this task handles accounts that have a dob older than 120 years ago"""

    date_cutoff = datetime.now() - timedelta(years=120)

    accounts_with_dob_more_than_120_years_ago = Account.objects.filter(
        dob__lte=date_cutoff
    )
    
    for account in accounts_with_dob_more_than_120_years_ago:
        # do something ...
```

**views.py**

```py
from .tasks import handle_age_over_120_years

class AgeCheckerView(APIView):
    """a sample class for triggering the task"""

    def post(self, request):
        """on post, trigger task"""

        handle_age_over_120_years()

        return Response("ok")
```

**urls.py**

```py
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('age-checker-task', views.AgeCheckerView.as_view(), name='age-checker-task'),
]
```

Consider:

- by placing the core logic in a separate task, you can have the task triggered by a variety of sources, i.e. a POST request, or celery, etc.
- you can add restrictions to your `AgeCheckerView`, for example only allowing specific users to call this view and trigger the task
- you can call the endpoint at anytime, so you can set something up (like AWS lambda) to call it on a schedule, and you can manually trigger it by sending a POST request when needed

Caveats:

- once the number of accounts grows large enough, this method may no longer suffice (it could take too long, for example); at this stage you may want to consider alternative solutions